# ListBox won't update in different class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, listbox

My Problem is, I want to insert strings from another class. The debugger told me, that the method is working fine and the string is filled with the stuff I need but somehow it won't appear in my ListBox in `cstmAntraege`. The string is transferred over `Data.cs` with the methods `GetAnwender` and `SetAnwender` and it's working perfectly fine. So I only need to know how to transfer the `ListBox` data between the classes. And I should mention: I am working with Visual Studio so therefore I don't need to initialize the `ListBox` because it's done in the designer.

I searched the internet a whole day and found nothing working. I tried to use `Listbox.Update()`, `ListBox.Refresh()`, and `ListBox.invalidate()` (because someone told, that this is working). I found nothing else with my knowledge.

```
// Thats the class where the string and ListBox-data is from 
namespace FirewallDB_Client
{
    public partial class NeuerAnwender : Form
    {
        // ... some code ...

        // thats where the whole thing starts
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cstmAntraege jobStart = new cstmAntraege();

            string Anwender = "'" + txtUserID.Text + "', '" + txtVorname.Text + "', '" + txtNachname.Text + "', '" + txtEMail.Text + "', '" + txtFirma.Text + "'";
            Data.SetAnwender(Anwender); //here the string is transfered into the data class
            jobStart.AnwenderReload();  //and thats where i try to start the job in the other class where the listbox is
        }
    }
}


//thats the class where the listbox is and where the method is written
namespace FirewallDB_Client
{
    public partial class cstmAntraege : Form
    {

        // ... some code ...

        // after starting the method my programm jumps to this point
        public void AnwenderReload()
        {
            string Anwenderzw = ".";
            string Anwender = Data.GetAnwender();
            if (Anwender != Anwenderzw)
            {
                lbAnwender.Items.Add(Data.GetAnwender()); //and there is where the string gets into an not existing listbox (i also tried a normal string like "test")
                lbAnwender.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got in the `cstmAntraege` form a `Listbox`, where the string from the `NeuerAnwender` form should appear.

Comment: is `Data` static? please post the `Data` class. I don't see any `cstmAntraege.Show()` don't you intend to show the other form?

Comment: This behavior suggest me that you are creating a new instance of the cstmAntraege form and the data is correctly set in that instance but you expect the data to be shown in the current instance of cstmAntraege that you have already shown. How do you create that variable _jobStart_?

Comment: @MongZhu the data class is only for transfering the string, which works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Steve cstmAntraege should be a formular, in which you can insert personal data. To add more persons i created the class NeuerAnwender, in which you can insert the personal data like Name, Email etc. Then after pressing the save button, it should insert the information in the ListBox in my currently open formular cstmAntraege (the information is packed into the string "Anwender".) JobStart should be created with 'cstmAntraege JobStart = new cstmAntraege'.

Comment: _cstmAntraege jobStart = new cstmAntraege();_ this line creates a new instance of the form _cstmAntraege_. This new instance is invisible until you call _jobStart.Show()_ and you are adding items to the listbox belonging to the _jobStart_ instance. If you want to add items to an already existing instance of the _cstmAntraege_ then you need to use a variable that references that instance not create a new instance

Comment: if you want to use `Data` as storage container you need either to pass the instance of it to `cstmAntraege` (if it is not a static class) or you need to make it static so that you can use it the way that you are doing it right now. You probably have the wrong instance of `Data` in the second form

Comment: @Steve and how can i tell cstmAntraege to watch after changes? Like => if (Anwender.changed) something like this. Is there an update method or something similar? I'm sorry but my knowledge is very limited since i'm new to C#.

Comment: @MongZhu the data class is working perfectly fine. Its just to transfer strings between classes. public static string GetAnwender() {return Anwender}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to reference the correct instance of your form and then call the methods that updates its content. You con retrieve the current instance of your form (the one that you have already displayed and you are looking at) from the Application.OpenForms collection. With that instance you can work with your data

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cstmAntraege jobStart = Application.OpenForms.OfType<cstmAntraege>().FirstOrDefault();
    if(jobStart == null)
    {
        jobStart = new cstmAntraege();
        jobStart.Show();
    }
    string Anwender = "'" + txtUserID.Text + "', '" + txtVorname.Text + "', '" + txtNachname.Text + "', '" + txtEMail.Text + "', '" + txtFirma.Text + "'";
    Data.SetAnwender(Anwender); //here the string is transfered into the data class
    jobStart.AnwenderReload();  //and thats where i try to start the job in the other class where the listbox is
}
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but it's telling me (when i hover over .OpenForms) "Non-invocable member 'Application.OpenForms' cannot be used like a method." It's inside the private void btnSave...  so i don't understand why it's giving me this error. using System.Windows.Forms is implemented too.

Comment: My bad. OpenForms is a property not a method. No need for () after OpenForms

Comment: It's nearly the solution. It works with:

object o =Application.OpenForms.OfType<cstmAntraege>().FirstOrDefault<cstmAntraege>(); 

and then 

cstmAntraege jobStart = (cstmAntraege)o;

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
listBox.Invalidate();
```

It tells a control to redraw.

Maybe the items are cached and not rendered.

Comment: The OP says that he has already tried that and with no results.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't saw thst